# GNU Readline, статическое подключение к Qt

Tags: linux, qt, qtcreator, readline

Имеется Qt Creator с собранным Qt с флагом -static. Библиотеки qt успешно вшиваются в программу, а вот readline ([GNU Readline](http://www.delorie.com/gnu/docs/readline/rlman_23.html)) никак не желает. Каким образом надо настроить .pro - файл, чтобы readline вшилась в программу?

ОС: Ubuntu 14.xx. Файл libreadline.a в системе есть.

P.S.: проект с открытым исходным кодом будет, так что про GNU в курсе.

Comment: А проект случаем не связан с драйверами?

Comment: Ещё вопрос: нафига такой старый дистр? Если уже вышел 18.04 на котором в будущем прога и будет пахать.

Comment: @donRumata разве есть разница? Поставил первое, что нашёл. Для создания и тестирования вполне подошло + перенести дело пары часов. Не забывай, я работаю из под виртуальной машины.

Comment: "Поставил первое, что нашёл".

В продакшене тебе будет ой как непросто.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Сразу предупреждаю, на ответ не тянет, но в комментарий не поместится.

Собрал тест с `readline` (но без QT -)).

В самом деле

```
gcc -o t-r t-readline.c -static -lreadline
```

выдает *предупреждения* для некоторых функций `libc` (связанных с аутентификацией) и *ошибки на отсутствие функций* `tgetent`, `tputs`, `tgetflag` и т.п., вызываемых из функций библиотеки `readline`.

Понятно, что я не задал линкеру какую-то библиотеку (или несколько).

Узнать, какие библиотеки нужны помогает утилита [ldd](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/ldd.1.html) (*print shared object dependencies*).

Итак, собираем *shared* версию

```
gcc -o t-r t-readline.c -lreadline
```

и запускаем **`ldd`**

```
avp@avp-ubu1:hashcode$ ldd -v ./t-r
        linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007ffeb73e5000)
        libreadline.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libreadline.so.6 (0x00007fb39dd17000)
        libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007fb39d94d000)
        libtinfo.so.5 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtinfo.so.5 (0x00007fb39d724000)
        /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007fb39df5d000)

        Version information:
        ./t-r:
                libc.so.6 (GLIBC_2.7) => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
                libc.so.6 (GLIBC_2.4) => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
                libc.so.6 (GLIBC_2.2.5) => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
        /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libreadline.so.6:
                libtinfo.so.5 (NCURSES_TINFO_5.0.19991023) => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtinfo.so.5
                libc.so.6 (GLIBC_2.11) => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
                libc.so.6 (GLIBC_2.14) => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
                libc.so.6 (GLIBC_2.15) => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
                libc.so.6 (GLIBC_2.4) => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
                libc.so.6 (GLIBC_2.3.4) => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
                libc.so.6 (GLIBC_2.2.5) => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
                libc.so.6 (GLIBC_2.3) => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
        /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6:
                ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (GLIBC_2.3) => /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
                ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (GLIBC_PRIVATE) => /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
        /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtinfo.so.5:
                libc.so.6 (GLIBC_2.3) => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
                libc.so.6 (GLIBC_2.14) => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
                libc.so.6 (GLIBC_2.16) => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
                libc.so.6 (GLIBC_2.4) => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
                libc.so.6 (GLIBC_2.3.4) => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
                libc.so.6 (GLIBC_2.2.5) => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
```

Из полученного вывода делаем предположение, что скорее всего нам нужна **`libtinfo`**.

Пробуем

```
avp@avp-ubu1:hashcode$ gcc -o t-r t-readline.c -static -lreadline -ltinfo
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libreadline.a(complete.o): In function `rl_username_completion_function':
(.text+0x3f69): warning: Using 'getpwent' in statically linked applications requires at runtime the shared libraries from the glibc version used for linking
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libreadline.a(tilde.o): In function `tilde_expand_word':
(.text+0x1c4): warning: Using 'getpwnam' in statically linked applications requires at runtime the shared libraries from the glibc version used for linking
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libreadline.a(shell.o): In function `sh_get_home_dir':
(.text+0xf9): warning: Using 'getpwuid' in statically linked applications requires at runtime the shared libraries from the glibc version used for linking
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libreadline.a(complete.o): In function `rl_username_completion_function':
(.text+0x3f5f): warning: Using 'setpwent' in statically linked applications requires at runtime the shared libraries from the glibc version used for linking
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libreadline.a(complete.o): In function `rl_username_completion_function':
(.text+0x4009): warning: Using 'endpwent' in statically linked applications requires at runtime the shared libraries from the glibc version used for linking
avp@avp-ubu1:hashcode$
```

смотрим результат

```
avp@avp-ubu1:hashcode$ file t-r
t-r: ELF 64-bit LSB executable, x86-64, version 1 (GNU/Linux), statically linked, for GNU/Linux 2.6.32, BuildID[sha1]=e0ee17d4201c7070bf650e9ac2bac441f6628a51, not stripped
avp@avp-ubu1:hashcode$
```

потом слегка "тестируем"

```
avp@avp-ubu1:hashcode$ ./t-r
> djjdjj
line: djjdjj
> kdkk dkkdkk dk
line: kdkk dkkdkk dk
> kdkk dkkm   49949 dkk dk
line: kdkk dkkm   49949 dkk dk
> End
avp@avp-ubu1:hashcode$
```

и видим, что затея удалась.

P.S.
Warnings, наверное, тоже можно побороть.

Comment: Ваш ответ полностью подошёл, все заработало прекрасно. Единственное, я не собирал из исходного кода, а пришивал к проекту Qt, и ldd жалуется..Скорее всего из-за различия разрядностей. Пересобрать дело техники...